# Where is arrayfire/lib64 and libafcu?

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu-14.04, arrayfire

After I build and install arrayfire, and I read the complete documentation in http://www.arrayfire.com/docs/createprojects.htm#createprojects_linux, bur I could not find the `arrayfire/lib64` in my computer, so how to set up Environment Variable `AF_PATH`?

```
export AF_PATH=/home/arrayfire
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$AF_PATH/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And I also didn't find `libafcu.so`, so there is problem when add the flags described in the hyperlink above:

```
 g++ *.cpp -lafcu
```

I wonder if there is any thing I have misunderstand? This is my first time trying to programe in linux.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just replace -lafcu with -lafcuda and there is no directory $AF_PATH/lib64 anymore, but when change the library directory to $AF_PATH/lib, the problem could be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the examples to compile because of the same issue you mentioned. Instead of `-lafcu`, link against `libafcuda.so` by using `-lafcuda`. It seems that the latest commit in the master branch has changes a few things here and there.

If you do `make install` after the compilation, the dynamic library files will be copied in `/usr/local/lib` (under Ubuntu 14.04) (you'll have `libafcpu.so` and `libafcuda.so`). Thus, set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly.

Comment: @jeffreyp If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as the answer so that other's will know that this question is solved.